# Too many categories defined in ATL Trace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, atl

I upgraded a project from VS2012 to VS2013, the release version works correctly but the debug version fails on an assert.

Before `main` I slowly watch the `RegisterCategory` exceed the max number of categories. Stepping through the debugger they all seem like reasonably titled categories, and then the thing fails the assert.

Confusingly, functions in `atltrace.h` such as the following appear to be called more than once. With different function addresses, I suppose this wouldn't be a problem if not for the 32 limit.

```
__declspec(selectany) CTraceCategoryEx<CTraceCategoryEx<>::TraceISAPI> atlTraceISAPI(_T("atlTraceISAPI"));
```

Whats going on? Can I disable atltrace?

```
static void RegisterCategory(_In_z_ LPCTSTR pszCategory, unsigned int nCategory)
    {
        if (pszCategory == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (m_nLastCategory >= MaxCategoryArray) 
        {
            ATLASSERT(false && "Too many categories defined");
            return;
        }

        m_nMap[m_nLastCategory].nCategory = nCategory;
#ifdef _UNICODE
        wcscpy_s(m_nMap[m_nLastCategory].categryName, MaxLengthOfCategoryName - 1, pszCategory);
#else
        wchar_t buffer[MaxLengthOfCategoryName] = { 0 };    
        swprintf_s(buffer, MaxLengthOfCategoryName - 1, L"%S", pszCategory);
        wcscpy_s(m_nMap[m_nLastCategory].categryName, MaxLengthOfCategoryName - 1, buffer);
#endif

        m_nLastCategory++;
    }
```

Linker 2012 (working)

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\\mine.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\mine.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\fslim\\glew\glew-1.9.0\lib\glew32.lib" "C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\fslim\\glew\glew-1.9.0\lib\glew32mx.lib" "C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\fslim\\Andor SDK3\atcorem.lib" "BNSPCIeBoard.lib" "cudart.lib" "cuda.lib" "WINMM.lib" "libgmp-10.lib" "libtiff.lib" "qtmaind.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5OpenGLd.lib" "Qt5PrintSupportd.lib" "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "opencv_core300d.lib" "opencv_cuda300d.lib" "opencv_cudaarithm300d.lib" "opencv_cudaimgproc300d.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /PGD:"C:\Users\kandel\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\mine.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\SLIM4.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\lib\x64" /TLBID:1
```

VS 2013 Not Working

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\QLI\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\\mine.exe" /MANIFEST:NO /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\QLI\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\mine.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "C:\Users\QLI\Desktop\obfuscated\\Andor SDK3\atcorem.lib" "BNSPCIeBoard.lib" "cudart.lib" "cuda.lib" "WINMM.lib" "libgmp-10.lib" "libtiff.lib" "qtmaind.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5OpenGLd.lib" "Qt5PrintSupportd.lib" "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "opencv_core300d.lib" "opencv_cuda300d.lib" "opencv_cudaarithm300d.lib" "opencv_cudaimgproc300d.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /PGD:"C:\Users\QLI\Desktop\obfuscated\x64\Debug\mine.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\mine.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013_64_opengl\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\lib\x64" /TLBID:1
```

The principle difference between these two is that in VS2012 I could choose `no atl` and everything ran well/correctly, wherein in VS2013 I can't choose this option.

**--edit--**

I removed all externals libraries except Qt and CUDA. Noticed that removing `#include <afxwin.h>` from the precompiled header makes the problem go away, although I need to use `afxwin.h`...

Comment: You somehow broke __declspec(selectany).  A known problem with Intel's ICC btw.  Your linker settings are surely relevant.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response, I'm using VS for linking. I'm wondering how `selectany` chooses which library to load when you have both debug and release dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the problem by moving the `afx` portion of my code into a dll and removing the header. Why this functionality changed between VS version is a lingering question. I can only conclude the MS broke my code by changing the max numbers that can be registered.

Answer (score -1):

MaxCategoryArray = sizeof(unsigned int) * 80, //original *8// 32 category names possible

modify the atltrace.h, then it works.
But don't know if there are any after-effects, but for debug , I think it is enough.

--edit--
check the define of "MaxCategoryArray" in "atltrace.h",it's default value is 32:
`MaxCategoryArray = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8, // 32 category names possible`

it's not big enough,just change it as above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).